# jQuery UI: Button opens Dialog / Button doesn't change status

Tags: css, jquery-ui, button

if I use a button to open a dialog, the button doesn't change the status to normal (stay on ui-state-hover).
How can I tell the button to change back after clicking on it?

Hope some1 can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe ui-state-focus is the class that's being added when the button is clicked.  If you add this to the end of the buttons 'click' event, it should reset it to a normal state.

`$('#button').toggleClass('ui-state-focus');`